# CKEditor - clear contents on first focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm new to using CKEditor, and the API is a little confusing...

What I want to do is to clear the contents of the CKEditor on the first focus by the user, and only if the form hasn't been reloaded.

Why? I'm putting some instructions in the CKEditor field itself and would like for it to get cleared the first time they focus the editor. I don't want the contents to get cleared on subsequent focuses.

Thanks for any help!

The JS framework I'm using is jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by storing the contents in the session. If the form round-trips to the server and fails validation, I just load the contents from the session. I store it to the session via Ajax on `blur` event. Once the form validates and posts to the db I destroy the session.

Answer (score 2):

declare a global variable in javascript,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isFirst = 1;

</script>
and then try adding onfocus event , like this:
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on( 'onfocus', function( evt ) {
if(isFirst)
{
  isFirst = 0;
  CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData( '' );
}
});
```

Comment: That works...but what about form reloads? If the form gets sent to the server and doesn't validate I don't want their input to get cleared when it comes back to the client and get erased when they focus the editor.